# Is there a way to determine in angular.js if there are url query parameters present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular routes, you can parse the url arguments into $routeParams.  However, I need to know what's the best way to see if they exist.

For example, I have several `$routeParams` from different parts of the URL however, all I want to know is whether any url params exist (if the ? exists and parameters after). I understand, I can just do a search for the ? but wanted to know if there was a way within angular.

Here's my code:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/sports/:sport_id/:args?',
```

sport_id and all the args will be combined in $routeParams.  However I just want to know if args exist. (the query parameters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject `$routeParams` and look for the presence of any properties in the object.

ex: `var hasParams = Boolean(Object.keys($routeParams).length);`

You dont need the `Boolean(` part as 0 will be falsy anyways, however just being more explicit.

If looking for just the query string params you can just inject `$location` service and use `$location.search()` it will provide object with query string argument as key value pair on the object.

Comment: Yes, but won't this also return true if I have routeParams from the URL other than after the '?'

Comment: @KingKongFrog No. $routeparams object will only populated with specific properties if they are configured and present in the url.

Comment: I've added more info to the question to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use `$location.search()`

Comment: location search is what I was looking for :)